# YUI, instantiable module that is not a widget?

Tags: yui, yui3

If I want a module that is instantiable, let say, a module that handles storing preferences in a subcookies, and i want the main cookie to be configurable, but i don't want it to be a widget... what patterns should i use with YUI?

the end code should be something:

```
Y.use('my-pref-manager', function(Y){
    var A = Y.my-pref-manager.prefStore('A"),
        B = Y.my-pref-manager.prefStore('B");
    // A and B are now loaded with the contents of cookies A and B, if they exist
    A.set('xy', 123 );
});
```

So far i either found patterns that create widgets within my-module or i have to use methods directly in my-method which will be globals and lack initializers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of ways of doing this. You could do it using `Y.Base.create`, like below. The code might not be production ready, or even working properly, but hopefully it answers how you can create a module without it being a Widget.

The code below creates a module that extends `Y.Base`. This let us use `Attributes` and other cool things. Check the [doc for Y.Base](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Base.html).

```
YUI.add('my-pref-manager', function (Y) {

    var PrefManager = Y.Base.create('myPrefManager', Y.Base, [], {

        initializer: function () {
            this.after('prefsChange', this.changePref);
        },

        changePref: function (e) {
            Y.Cookie.setSub(this.get('prefStore'), e.subAttrName, this.get(e.subAttrName));
        },

        setPref: function (name, val) {
            this.set('prefs.'+name, val);
        },

        getPref: function (name) {
            return this.get('prefs.'+name);
        }


    }, {
        ATTRS: {
            prefStore: { 
                value: null,
                setter: function (val) {
                    return Y.Cookie.set(val, val);
                }
            },
            prefs: {
                value: {}
            }
        }
    });

    Y.namespace('My').PrefManager = PrefManager;

}, '0.0.1', {
    requires: ['base', 'cookie']
});

YUI().use('my-pref-manager', function (Y) {
    var A = new Y.My.PrefManager({prefStore: 'userPrefs'}),
        B = new Y.My.PrefManager({prefStore: 'displayPrefs'});

    A.setPref('x', 3);
    A.setPref('y', 54);

    B.setPref('tty', 7);

    console.log(A.getPref('x')); // 3
});
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/B62nu/